# How to create inverted index for a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, nltk, tf-idf

I created a data frame for my **scraped** data and removed punctuations, stopwords and tokenized it.
How do I create inverted index for the columns name and brand ?

```
import nltk
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import pandas as pd
```

```
tokens = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
macys_df['name'] = macys_df['name'].apply(lambda x: tokens.tokenize(x.lower()))
macys_df.head()
```

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
stop_words = stop_words.union(",","(",")","[","]","{","}","#","@","!",":",";",".","?")

macys_df['name'] = macys_df['name'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop_words])
```

```
Output - 
macys_df['name'].head()
0    [versa, 2, black, elastomer, strap, touchscree...
1    [men, digital, black, resin, strap, watch, 50,...
2      [versa, lite, white, strap, smart, watch, 39mm]
3    [access, mkgo, black, silicone, strap, touchsc...
4    [inspire, black, strap, activity, tracker, 19,...
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code directly, not as images or links. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html